# vb.net: can't store multiple urls in different buttons using a function

Tags: vb.net, function

so basically that's a browser code, I'm facing a problem when trying to save links of favorite sites in a favorite button. Problem is When i Click the button btnFav1 or btnFav2, type in the name, type it the url i wanna store It appears perfect. but when i click it for the second time it doesn't take me to the site, instead (About:blank) appears in the url bar.

```
Public Class Form1
Dim UrlF1,UrlF2,UrlF3,UrlF4,UrlF5 As string
Function FavUrl
    Dim Url As string = Inputbox("Enter Url")
    Return Url   
End Function
sub fav(a As object,b As object,c As string)

    If a.text = "" then
        a.Text = FavName 
        c = FavUrl
        b.Visible = true
    Else
        txtURL.text = c
        btnGo.PerformClick
    End If

End sub
Function FavName
    Dim Name As String = InputBox("What do you wanna call it?")
    Return Name   
End Function
Sub NavBar
    txtURL.Text = UrlReturn
End sub
Function UrlReturn
    Return WB.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri 
End Function
Private Sub btnFavs_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFavs1.Click
    fav(btnfavs1,btnfavs2,UrlF1)
End Sub
Private Sub btnFavs2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFavs2.Click
    fav(btnfavs2,btnfavs3,UrlF2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Where to you pass the result of "c = FavUrl" back to the textbox?

Comment: isn't the c representing the UrlF1? thus UrlF1 = FavUrl I was hoping to store the first link in UrlF1 and the second link in UrlF2,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be an alternative way of achieving your goal without all the fuss:

```
  Private Sub ButtonClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnFavs1.Click, btnFavs2.Click, btnFavs3.Click

        Try
            Dim thisBtn As Button = DirectCast(sender, Button)

            If thisBtn.Text.Length = 0 Then
                thisBtn.Text = InputBox("What do you want to call it?")
                thisBtn.Tag = InputBox("The URL") 'WB.Document.Url.AbsoluteUri
            Else
                txtURL.Text = thisBtn.Tag.ToString
                btnGo.PerformClick()
            End If

        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Comment: Buttons on my program are toolstripbuttons so i had to modify the part where it says `as button`. Now lets say that i want to make all the buttons hidden but the first. when I set up the first the second becomes visible. Now how would I do that?

Comment: Have a look at your form's `Me.Controls.Find` method.